# setting mfg in a multi plot prevents drawin on margin

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to add common axes to a bunch of plots by putting them in the outer margin.
Plots are drawn first in a loop (not in the example) then I wanted to draw axes on the bottom of the two rows of plots.

But drawing the axis outside the plotting region is only possible without `mfg` being changed. How can I enable out-of-plot-drawing after changing `mfg`?

```
par(mfrow=c(2,2),
mar=c(1,1,0,0),
oma=c(3,0,0,0))

#Some plots
plot(function(x)x^2,from=-1,to=2,  frame.plot=T,axes=F)
plot(function(x)x^3,from=-2,to=2,  frame.plot=T,axes=F)
plot(rnorm(10),  frame.plot=T,axes=F)
plot(1:10,       frame.plot=T,axes=F)
# axis on last drawn plot (mfg=c(2,2)) - works
axis(side=1,line=0,outer=TRUE)

# set mfg to same value (mfg=c(2,2))
par(mfg=c(2,2))

# red axis is clipped to plot region, even with xpd?
axis(side=1,line=-.2,outer=FALSE,xpd=NA,col="red")
par(mfg=c(2,1))
axis(side=1,line=-.2,outer=FALSE,xpd=NA,col="red")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set :

```
par(xpd=NA)
```

to make sure that the axis is not clipped to the plotting region.

Comment: Thank you! I tried this by specifying xpd=NA in axis() arguments, but that didn't work. Furthermore, xpd=NA has to be set before mfg is set, for some reason.